# Compiler error "cannot resolve symbol" with nested namespaces

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, compiler-errors, namespaces

I have reduced my problem to the following code.

```
using WeinCad.Plugin.MoineauMachinePath;
namespace WeinCad.Plugin.Foo
{
    public class Foo
    {
         // This line is a compiler error
         // (Cannot resolve symbol MoineauMachinePath )
         private WeinCad.Plugin.MoineauMachinePath.MachinePathSolverPropertiesViewModel X;

         // Implicity referenced it is ok
         private MachinePathSolverPropertiesViewModel Y;

    }
}
```

If I use an explicit reference to a class then I am getting a compiler error. To prove the namespace is correct I also import the namespace into scope and reference the class implicitly. Only the explicit reference is in error.

**EDIT**

[image]

The intellisense shows that there is a namespace nested double like so. That will be the source of the problem. Not sure how it code there.

**EDIT**

Source of the problem was a corrupted Resources.Designer.cs file.

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.18444
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace WeinCad.Plugin.WeinCad.Plugin.BasicFolders.Properties
{
    using System;
```

Not sure how this happened. Deleting the Resources file and then recreating it I get

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.18444
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace WeinCad.Plugin.BasicFolders.Properties {
    using System;
```

without the nasty duplicate. It's still an open question on how this happened.

Comment: did you try `global::WeinCad.Plugin.MoineauMachinePath.MachinePathSolverPropertiesViewModel` ?

Comment: For info, this works: http://pastie.org/9277079 - so whatever the problem is, it needs more code than just the code you are showing

Comment: Yeah that worked but why?  The real problem is in a "g.cs" file generated by the XAML compiler so I can't do that simple fix.

Comment: _"The real problem is in a g.cs file"_ - so totally different from the posted code?

Comment: Post the XAML, esp all the xmlns attributes.

Comment: The only way I can get anything *like* that error is to define a `WeinCad` and a `WeinCad+Plugin` inside `Foo`. Is this possibly the case?

Comment: No the same error occurs in the posted code as in the "g.cs" code. A bit hasty with the -1 there :) but I think I found the reason.

Comment: @MarcGravell you are right. Not sure how it happened but I'll edit the post to show evidence of what you guessed.

Comment: @MarcGravell If you want the points you  can put your comment into an answer and I'll give it to you as it was your hint that made me start looking in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That error message suggests that there is a `WeinCad.Plugin` **inside** the current scope, i.e. either `WeinCad.Plugin.Foo.Foo.WeinCad.Plugin`, or `WeinCad.Plugin.Foo.WeinCad.Plugin`. When the compiler is looking for `WeinCad.Plugin`, it looks *first* at the local scopes, and only if it can't find a match does it look at the global scope.

The *simplest and most correct* fix for this is: don't have a scope that duplicates names inside itself (that is just asking for trouble). The other option is to *explicitly specify* the global scope, using the `global::` prefix in front of the full type name, i.e. `global::WeinCad.Plugin.Whatever`.